# windows phone & sound cloud

Tags: windows-phone-8, soundcloud

I would like to know if there is a "good" way to use one of the Soundcloud's API with windows phone 8 ? Because I haven't find a dedicated API, only Python, Ruby, PHP, Java, iOS and JavaScript.

So my Idea was to create a web service using the PHP API, so my wp8 app could use soundcloud through the web service with an http request or something like that.

What do you think about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just port one of the SoundCloud libraries to C#/Basic? I found [a Visual Basic](http://www.mpgh.net/forum/33-visual-basic-programming/723497-soundcloud-api-class.html) library from a quick search, and I'm sure you could find more.

Comment: Do you suggest me to create my own c# wrapper for Soundcloud ? If it's the case, I think I don't have enough time for this unfortunately (and I don't even know how to do that !):/ It's for my university project witch ends in 3 weeks